# How do I use system to call a .jar in Octave?

Tags: java, octave

I am running Windows 10 x64, Octave 5.1.0 x64, and the latest JRE.  I would like to use the command line version of tabula from within Octave:

system(['java -jar c:\path\to\tabula\tabula.jar -format JSON -lattice -t -u -p 1-3 "input.pdf"']);

This code does not run, and throws up an error immediately.  When I remove the options, it appears to at least start running, but it gives a different set of errors.  So I think I have at least two issues, one of which is the way I call options.

```
system(['java -jar "c:\path\to\tabula\tabula.jar" "input.pdf"']);
```

I have tried including options with no hyphens, single hyphens, double hypens, and I've tried defining strings with single and double quotes (with appropriate escapes).  I've also tried the complete path to the files as well just the file names when the command line is in the same folder as both the jar and the pdf.

I get the following error if I include options:

```
2019-06-06 12:11:35.497:INFO::main: Logging initialized @459ms
2019-06-06 12:11:35.502:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
ERROR: Context 'file:/C:/path/to/jar/but/not.jar/itself/format' does not exist
Usage: java [-Djetty.home=dir] -jar jetty-runner.jar [--help|--version] [ server opts] [[ context opts] context ...]
Server opts:
 --version                           - display version and exit
 --log file                          - request log filename (with optional 'yyyy_mm_dd' wildcard
 --out file                          - info/warn/debug log filename (with optional 'yyyy_mm_dd' wildcard
 --host name|ip                      - interface to listen on (default is all interfaces)
 --port n                            - port to listen on (default 8080)
 --stop-port n                       - port to listen for stop command
 --stop-key n                        - security string for stop command (required if --stop-port is present)
 [--jar file]*n                      - each tuple specifies an extra jar to be added to the classloader
 [--lib dir]*n                       - each tuple specifies an extra directory of jars to be added to the classloader
 [--classes dir]*n                   - each tuple specifies an extra directory of classes to be added to the classloader
 --stats [unsecure|realm.properties] - enable stats gathering servlet context
 [--config file]*n                   - each tuple specifies the name of a jetty xml config file to apply (in the order defined)
Context opts:
 [[--path /path] context]*n          - WAR file, web app dir or context xml file, optionally with a context path
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException


I get the following errors if I don't include options:


2019-06-06 12:39:05.288:INFO::main: Logging initialized @474ms
2019-06-06 12:39:05.294:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
2019-06-06 12:39:05.420:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.9.v20150224
2019-06-06 12:39:23.272:WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. Class hierarchy: empty
INFO: jruby 9.1.15.0 (2.3.3) 2017-12-07 929fde8 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.211-b12 on 1.8.0_211-b12 +jit [mswin32-x86_64]
INFO: using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2019-06-06 12:39:32.319:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2ff5659e{/,file:/C:/Users/ned/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.
0.0-8080-tabula121.jar-_-any-3946933838247600913.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/C:/Users/path/to/tabula/tabula121.jar}
2019-06-06 12:39:32.386:WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. Class hierarchy: empty
2019-06-06 12:39:32.450:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@77afea7d{/,file:/C:/Users/ned/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.
0.0-8080-input.pdf-_-any-1670794067818399886.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/D:/path/to/input.pdf}
2019-06-06 12:39:32.451:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2019-06-06 12:39:32.460:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@3ad847f8{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Addre
ss already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:557)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at WarMain.launchWebServer(WarMain.java:187)
        at WarMain.start(WarMain.java:345)
        at JarMain.doStart(JarMain.java:233)
        at WarMain.main(WarMain.java:367)
2019-06-06 12:39:32.461:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@224aed64: java.net.BindException: Address alrea
dy in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:557)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at WarMain.launchWebServer(WarMain.java:187)
        at WarMain.start(WarMain.java:345)
        at JarMain.doStart(JarMain.java:233)
        at WarMain.main(WarMain.java:367)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:557)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at WarMain.launchWebServer(WarMain.java:187)
        at WarMain.start(WarMain.java:345)
        at JarMain.doStart(JarMain.java:233)
        at WarMain.main(WarMain.java:367)
Usage: java [-Djetty.home=dir] -jar jetty-runner.jar [--help|--version] [ server opts] [[ context opts] context ...]
Server opts:
 --version                           - display version and exit
 --log file                          - request log filename (with optional 'yyyy_mm_dd' wildcard
 --out file                          - info/warn/debug log filename (with optional 'yyyy_mm_dd' wildcard
 --host name|ip                      - interface to listen on (default is all interfaces)
 --port n                            - port to listen on (default 8080)
 --stop-port n                       - port to listen for stop command
 --stop-key n                        - security string for stop command (required if --stop-port is present)
 [--jar file]*n                      - each tuple specifies an extra jar to be added to the classloader
 [--lib dir]*n                       - each tuple specifies an extra directory of jars to be added to the classloader
 [--classes dir]*n                   - each tuple specifies an extra directory of classes to be added to the classloader
 --stats [unsecure|realm.properties] - enable stats gathering servlet context
 [--config file]*n                   - each tuple specifies the name of a jetty xml config file to apply (in the order defined)
Context opts:
 [[--path /path] context]*n          - WAR file, web app dir or context xml file, optionally with a context path
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException


In Octave I have put the path to tabula on the javaclasspath.  When I type "javaclasspath" in Octave, I get:

    STATIC JAVA PATH
      C:\correct\path\to\tabula.jar

This is driving me crazy.  Thanks so much for your help!
```

Comment: Does that command work on the command line outside of Octave? If so, it might be an issue of proper environment variables being set (Java class path, `%PATH%`, etc.) These settings could cause the wrong Java runtime to be used, or it finding different versions of the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It doesn't work in a cmd either.  It worked in Matlab, so I was blaming octave.  But I guess Matlab was doing something behind the scenes to make it work...

Comment: MATLAB runs in the JVM, you wouldn’t need to call `system('java...')` there. But yes, MATLAB heavily changes the environment, it likely has the Java class path set differently than you’d have it in the normal shell.

Comment: putting the jar file on the classpath shouldn't have anything to do with this since you're trying to run it as a system command, rather than the octave-java interface. That Error is interesting ... does it not tell you anything that you recognise? Is that a pathname that you have on your system? `ERROR: Context 'file:/C:/Users/path/to/jar/but/not.jar/itself/format' does not exist` ... oh wait, I see what you did there. (facepalm).

Comment: have you tried specifying the input.pdf by absolute path too?

Comment: re: absolute path.  Yes, I did try that. good thought though.  I'll add that to the original post.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou  I don't see anything meaningful in the error, though I think it's really strange that near the top, the error starting with "ERROR: Context" says that the file does not exist, but it doesn't include the file name, and *does* include the first option I include.  But I have no idea what to make of that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out. I had shortened the .jar filename because it was really long. As you all probably know, this is Not Allowed. That was a day-wasting mistake. I restored the original filename and it's all systems go.  Hopefully this note helps someone else. Never change .jar filenames! Thanks to you all for giving me some of your time.